# mariaDB keep failing to complete INSERT INTO request even though the syntax is right

Tags: mariadb

I'm getting errors when I execute the following SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (sid, uid, hostname, session, timestamp) 
VALUES('thisisatest', 73, '100.100.100.100', '', 1234567890);
```

Error:

```
Field 'desc' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO sessions (desc, sid, uid, hostname, session, timestamp) 
VALUES('', 'thisisatest', 73, '100.100.100.100', '', 1234567890);
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, sid, uid, hostname, session, timestamp) VALUES('', '5tvdbif164aa4ve', 73, ' at line 1`
```

When I am trying to insert a row into the table, it always fails even though I have checked the syntax again and again...

Comment: Several of  your column names are reserved words (desc, session and timestamp) so you must enclose them with backticks. Or choose and use different column names.

Comment: The first error is because you did not specify something for the `desc` column and it is not defined as being able to be null.